# Separate indexes on two columns and unique constraint on the pair in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

My app uses a PostgreSQL database. I've got a migration that looks like this:

```
class CreateTagAssignments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tag_assignments do |t|
      t.integer :tag_id
      t.integer :quote_id
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :tag_assignments, :tag_id
    add_index :tag_assignments, :quote_id
  end
end
```

Records will be quite frequently searched by these two columns so I want to have a separate index for each. But now I'd like to enforce uniqueness of the pair (`tag_id`, `quote_id`) on the database level. I tried `add_index :tag_assignments, [:tag_id, :quote_id], unique: true` but I got the error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  could not create unique index "index_tag_assignments_on_tag_id_and_quote_id"
DETAIL:  Key (tag_id, quote_id)=(10, 1) is duplicated.
: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_tag_assignments_on_tag_id_and_quote_id" ON "tag_assignments" ("tag_id", "quote_id")
```

So multiple indexes apparently do the job of a multi-column index? If so, then I could add the constraint with `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT`, but how can I do it in ActiveRecord?

edit: manually performing `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT` produces the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Erwin points out, the "Key (tag_id, quote_id)=(10, 1) is duplicated" constraint violation error message tells you that your unique constraint is already violated by your existing data.  I infer from what's visible of your model that different users can each introduce a common association between a tag and a quote, so you see duplicates when you try to constrain uniqueness for just the quote_id,tag_id pair.  Compound indexes are still useful for index access on leading keys (though slightly less efficiently than a single column index since the compound index will have lower key-density). You could probably get the speed you require along with the appropriate unique constraint with two indexes, a single column index on one of the ids and a compound index on all three ids with the other id as its leading field.  If mapping from tag to quote was a more frequent access path than mapping from quote to tag, I would try this:

```
add_index :tag_assignments, :tag_id
add_index :tag_assignments, [:quote_id,:tag_id,:user_id], unique: true
```

If you're using Pg >= 9.2, you can take advantage of 9.2's index visibility maps to enable index-only scans of [covering indexes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Covering_indexes).  In this case there may be benefit to making the first index above contain all three ids, with tag_id and quote_id leading:

```
add_index :tag_assignments, [:tag_id,:quote_id,user_id]
```

It's unclear how user_id constrains your queries, so you may find that you want indexes with its position promoted earlier as well.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I misinterpreted the message, I thought the index was duplicated, forgot about checking data. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

> So multiple indexes apparently do the job of a multi-column index?

This conclusion is untrue as well as unfounded after what you describe. The error message indicates the opposite. A [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) or a `UNIQUE` constraint on multiple columns (implementing a multi-column index, too) provide functionality that you cannot get out of multiple single-column indexes.